# how to add new column and its data for attribute on product list grid on admin panel in magento

Tags: database, magento, attributes, grid, product

I have added a new  attribute 'productcategory' with three options for add product module to select product category and store in magento db but how to display productcategory column and data accordingly in product list grid.to add column and its data my code on

```
    app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php


    $this->addColumn('Product Category',
    array(

'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Category'),
'index' => 'productcategory',

));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find: `$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() within the _prepareCollection()` function.

And add:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('productcategory')
```

Comment: Already done .but showing only options id and not options name

Comment: use `->getAttributeText('attribute_code')` with renderer

Reference Link

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Comment: I added below code to display attribute label but filter not working on it                                                                                                      protected function _getAttributeOptions($attribute_code)
    {
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
        $options = array();
        foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
            $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
        return $options;
    }

Comment: and below code to add column<br/>                                              //code to add colum for product category
$this->addColumn('Product Category',
array(
 'header'    =>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Category'),
 'index'     =>'productcategory',
 'type'  => 'options',
  'options' => $this->_getAttributeOptions('productcategory'),
       
));
//end of code for product category           but now filter is not working on it

Comment: Use my code with renderer, I did it many time in my project. It will always work.